# How to parse a Text File with a certain logic to detect types as in description in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, filereader

For example if I have a file like this:

Type School

Name St Peter's

Place Denver

Type Student

Name Karl

Place Boulder

Name Raul

Place Denver

I now want to create a logic in C# that will read this .txt file and detect the "Type" first and insert the values into the database with the Data with a database table with columns "Type | Name | Place".

I would like the table to be like
**Type    | Name         | Place**
School  | St. Peter's  | Denver 
Student | Karl         | Boulder
Student | Raul         | Denver

The problem I have is that I am learning to parse files and am trying to figure out how to assign the type.

What I assume to be done is :
if there occurs an instance with type = "School" => continue type ="school" until there occurs another instance with type = "Student" => overwrite type = "student".

How do I write a logic for it?

```
private void btnParse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string strFilePath = txtFilePath.Text;
  FileStream fs = null;
  try
     {
        fs = new FileStream(strFilePath, FileMode.Open);
     }
  catch
     {
        throw new Exception("Error!!");
      }

  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

  // prime read
  line = sr.ReadLine();

  while (line != null)
   {

         // WRITE LOGIC HERE TO DETECT TYPE AND PUT VALUES IN DATABASE

    }
}
```

Comment: There's a logical flaw here that should send you back to the drawing board.  What if "Place" is a type, but "Park Place" is its value?  You never want to risk that sort of problem, as you'd only import "Park " and "Place" would be considered a type.  You could get around this with some logical catches, but at that point you're doing a lot of work to reinvent the wheel.  Either delimit the read using a character between  a "type" and a "value" and go line by line, or do what Brian Boitano'd do ; use an `XMLReader` and change your file structure to XML with your types as nodes..

Comment: I don't understand the paragraph starting “What I assume to be done is”. Can you show us an example?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a text file is always risky and should be avoided. Incase you don't have a way around it, error handling should be implemented so that the code fails gracefully.

Here is a sample code which you can use as a starting point. I am guessing you only need student data.

```
        // prime read
        string line = "Type School\r\nName St Peter's\r\nPlace Denver\r\nType Student\r\nName Karl\r\nPlace Boulder\r\nName Raul\r\nPlace Denver";

        List<string> Students = line.Substring ( line.IndexOf ( "Type Student" ) + 12 ).Split ( new string [ ] { "\r\nName" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ).ToList ( );

        foreach ( string student in Students )
        {
            string [ ] info = student.Replace ( "Place ", "" ).Split ( new [ ] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
            string Name = info [ 0 ].Trim ( );
            string Place = info [ 1 ].Trim ( );
        }
```